# Razor @{ } method on .cshtml page not allowing text or href selection

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have scaffolded my RegisterConfirmation page in .Net Core identity. My cshtml code is below.

```
@page
@model RegisterConfirmationModel
@using LazZiya.ExpressLocalization
@inject ISharedCultureLocalizer _loc
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = _loc[Model.PageTabTitle];
}

@section header_image{
    <div class="bg-img-non-home" id="RegisterPageBanner">
}
@section header_content{
    <div class="container-title">
        <div class="block-title">
            <br>
            <h1 class="block-subtitle-text" id="RegisterPageSubtitle">@_loc[Model.SubTitle]</h1>
            <h2 class="block-title-text-non-home" id="RegisterPageTitle">@_loc[Model.Title]</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
    <body class="body-bg-img">
        <div class="container-body">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <br />
                    <h2 class="font-style-content-head" id="RegisterConfHeading">@_loc[Model.Heading]</h2>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="container-body">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <hr />
                @{
                    if (@Model.DisplayConfirmAccountLink)
                    {
                        <p>
                            This app does not currently have a real email sender registered, see <a href="https://aka.ms/aspaccountconf">these docs</a> for how to configure a real email sender.
                            Normally this would be emailed: <a id="confirm-link" href="@Model.EmailConfirmationUrl">Click here to confirm your account</a>
                        </p>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>
                            Please check your email to confirm your account.
                        </p>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

If the `@section header_content` is present everything on the page displays. But the text from my `if` statement cannot be highlighted with the mouse and the `a href` links cannot be clicked. If I delete the code section below, then the text from my `if` statement can be highlighted using the mouse and the href works fine.

```
@section header_content{
    <div class="container-title">
        <div class="block-title">
            <br>
            <h1 class="block-subtitle-text" id="RegisterPageSubtitle">@_loc[Model.SubTitle]</h1>
            <h2 class="block-title-text-non-home" id="RegisterPageTitle">@_loc[Model.Title]</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** When I zoom in it works fine. Also, if I add lots of text inside the if statement, it doesn't wrap it simply goes past the width of the `body-bg-img` image. I can select the text when it is past the width of the page...

Comment: Looks like you are using bootstrap. You can use 'fixed-top' to anchor the top image https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#placement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a workaround than an answer. By pushing my text down the page using line breaks, it works fine. Not a solution for most other pages, but because this is only the register confirmation with few components on the page, I can make it work.

I'm guessing it is a css sizing issue with my `@section header_image`. One solution would probably be to check the css, or perhaps create a chopped header image with reduced height and use it on this page. But I don't need to bother in this case.

```
<body class="body-bg-img">
    <div class="container-body">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <br />
                <br />
                <h2 class="font-style-content-head" id="RegisterConfHeading">@_loc[Model.Heading]</h2>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container-body">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            @{
                if (@Model.DisplayConfirmAccountLink)
                {
                    <p>
                        This app does not currently have a real email sender registered, see <a href="https://aka.ms/aspaccountconf">these docs</a> for how to configure a real email sender.
                        Normally this would be emailed: <a id="confirm-link" href="@Model.EmailConfirmationUrl">Click here to confirm your account</a>
                    </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>
                        Please check your email to confirm your account.
                    </p>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Update:**
The above lasted about 60 seconds and I couldn't tolerate it! :) The issue was a hardcoded height value for my block-title css style. I changed it to auto and it is fine now. Still have a bit of tidying up to get the overall look back to my pages, but issue is resolved.

```
.block-title {
    width: 520px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```